# use cd in windows .bat file has no effect

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, for-loop, cd

i want to run git pull in a path for all projects, so i wrote a bat file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set dir=%1
if "%dir%"=="" (
    set dir=%~dp0
)
for /D /R "%dir%" %%i in (*) do (
    if exist %%i\.git (
        cd /d %%i
        rem no effect
        echo %cd%
        rem git pull
    )
)
pause
```

but is seems that cd in for loop does not take any effect, i don't know why.
can someone help me solve this problem?`enter code here`

Comment: Show an example output of the script. Changing the current directory inside a for loop looks dangerous.

Comment: Are you passing a different drive? If so, it'll change the directory, but git pull will execute on current drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has effect. But, in batch files, when a block of code (the code enclosed in parenthesis) is reached (the same for a line out of a block), variable reads are replaced with the value of the variable before executing the code in the block. So, when your `for` command is reached, the read of the `%cd%` variable is replaced with the value of the `%cd%` variable **before** executing the code. This speeds and simplifies execution of the code but generate this kind of problems.

You can enable delayed expansion with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command, and change the sintax from `%cd%` to `!cd!`. This tells cmd that that this variable read should be delayed until execution of the line.